# find and replace a pattern of string notepad++

Tags: regex

I have lines as below in notepad++

```
"00Xm0000000QtMZEA0","Account_Approval_Compliance_AD_Team04t20000000M1F1","Account Approval Compliance AD Team","00lm0000000DreXAAS","ADSS_Main_Folder_London"
```

I want to remove string starting with `04t` only, 
For example the above line should be changed to

```
"00Xm0000000QtMZEA0","Account_Approval_Compliance_AD_Team","Account Approval Compliance AD Team","00lm0000000DreXAAS","ADSS_Main_Folder_London"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find try this:
find what: `(.*)(?=04t)(.*?\")(.*)`
replace with: `$1\"$3`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about `notepad++`, but if you are looking for regex for that match here it is:

`04t.*\b`